# How can I hide pages in the navbar using rmarkdown's flexdashboard?

Tags: r, rstudio, r-markdown, flexdashboard

I am making a dashboard that visualizes data for different job ad postings for various companies. Right now I have it set up that there is a drop down list from the navbar that shows all the companies, but some companies have more that one application so I want to have a link on that page to the different applications dashboards (like a second menu). However, I can't figure out how to link to the dashboard page without having this show up in the navbar.. I've tried everything from setting data-navmenu to "null", "NULL", Null, etc. Nothing seems to be working. Does anyone know how to solve this problem or have suggestions for different ways to do it?

Here's a picture for reference... I'm trying to make it so the "Sales Manager" link isn't in the navbar at all :
[click here to see the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KdeX2.png)

Comment: Is this what you are expecting? 
http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/flexdashboard/using.html#page_navigation 
http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/flexdashboard/using.html#value_boxes (look into href)

Comment: @Sumedh Not exactly, I added a picture of what I'm trying to do for reference if that helps